# Conditional formatting based on a range of names

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make conditional formatting that changes the color of a cell (Red, Blue, Green) based on a range of names on a different sheet. What I have is three lists of names that are either Red, Blue or Green. When I make a list with these names on a separate sheet I want the formatting to change their color to the ones assigned.
The formatting I want to make is something along the lines of "IF the value (name) in this cell is the same as the value (name) in any of cell in a range on another sheet it should change the color automatically.

Here is a link to a sheet where I tried to set it up they way I wanted it to look but I still can't get the formatting to work

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i1DM8X6gyRNMUmYBAtuupeuCUA1iB4LhMDwkD7PHi8w/edit?usp=share_link

I was trying the conditional formatting tool with formulas but I kept getting errors with the formulas[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMbw6.png) The picture is in Swedish because google sheets would keep defaulting back to it regardless how much I tried.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is that Conditional Formatting doesn't allow you to directly refer to another sheet. You can do work it around via INDIRECT.

And to compare to several texts, you should not choose the option text contains, but you can find useful REGEXMATCH and TEXTJOIN:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A2;TEXTJOIN("|";1;INDIRECT("'Name sheet'!A2:A11")))
=REGEXMATCH(A2;TEXTJOIN("|";1;INDIRECT("'Name sheet'!B2:B11")))
=REGEXMATCH(A2;TEXTJOIN("|";1;INDIRECT("'Name sheet'!C2:C11")))
```

[image]